# SVG scale onmouseover - element disappears

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I've got an SVG map I made and I wanted it to change colour and increase in size on mouseover. I managed to get the colour change to work without issue, but when I try to scale the element, it totally disappears when I hover over it!

```
<g
   style="fill:#999999"
   id="newzealand"
   onmouseover="this.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(2)');this.style.fill='#83b901';document.getElementById('countryText').textContent='New Zealand';"
   onmouseout="this.style.fill='#999';document.getElementById('countryText').textContent='';"
   >
  <path
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="path3034"
     d="m 645,409.28571 -5,7.85715 -3.57143,2.85714 -2.5,5.71429 5.71429,1.42857 3.21428,-6.42857 0,-1.78572 2.14286,-0.71428 3.57143,-7.85715 z"
     style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="path3036"
     d="M 650.35714,411.07143 650,407.85714 l -1.78571,-2.14285 0.71428,-4.28572 -2.5,-6.78571 0,-1.42857 2.14286,2.85714 2.14286,2.5 2.85714,3.92857 2.14286,-1.78571 0,3.21428 -1.78572,2.14286 z"
     style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
</g>
```

I also tried using an animate element but got the same result. It seems to work fine with translate and rotate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your drawing isn't at the origin so when you scale it, it disappears off the edge of the page. m 645,409 effectively becomes m 1290,818. If we remove the doubling of the co-ordinates the drawing remains at the same point.

```
<g
   style="fill:#999999"
   id="newzealand"
   onmouseover="this.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(-645, -409) scale(2)');this.style.fill='#83b901';document.getElementById('countryText').textContent='New Zealand';"
   onmouseout="this.style.fill='#999';document.getElementById('countryText').textContent='';"
   >
  <path
     id="path3034"
     d="m 645,409.28571 -5,7.85715 -3.57143,2.85714 -2.5,5.71429 5.71429,1.42857 3.21428,-6.42857 0,-1.78572 2.14286,-0.71428 3.57143,-7.85715 z"
     style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     id="path3036"
     d="M 650.35714,411.07143 650,407.85714 l -1.78571,-2.14285 0.71428,-4.28572 -2.5,-6.78571 0,-1.42857 2.14286,2.85714 2.14286,2.5 2.85714,3.92857 2.14286,-1.78571 0,3.21428 -1.78572,2.14286 z"
     style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
</g>
```

Comment: Has anyone ever told you you're a genius? Thank you!