# RaphaelJS scale a path on hover

Tags: jquery, path, svg, raphael, scale

I would like to add a pop effect when I hover over a SVG path. What I have tried causes my paths to fly off past the bottom of the browser window.

I have read this post and attempted to compensate for the coordinate increase but it failed for my setup. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756423/svg-scale-onmouseover-element-disappears)

example of path:

```
var paths = {
lakes: {
    name: 'lakes',
           value: 'notSelected',
    path: 'm199,606l121,-45l18,60l-32,60l-52,157l-99,-9l-13,-70l-17,8l-22,0l-11,-30l9,-26l61,-45l12,-6l21,-35l4,-19z'
},
```

etc.

and I use for hover (only hover is shown)

```
obj.hover(function(){
if(paths[arr[this.id]].value == 'notSelected')
  {
        this.animate({
        fill: '#32CD32'
        }, 300);
  }
```

which works perfectly to fade in my chosen colour. I first added:

```
this.animate({transform: 'scale(1.1)'}, 300);
```

and this is when I spotted the path moving to the bottom so I tried to translate the coordinates with

```
this.animate({transform: 'translate(-199,-606)'}, 300);
```

and they still move away. Another member pointed out my paths were all drawing with a large Y, is this my problem?

(I redraw my SVG with `obj.attr(attributes).attr( { transform: "S0.81,0.81,150,-2000" } );` 
to counter this Y value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example works

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/EUwRq/

///// below did not work correctly in IE6,8 or 9 /////

I found a solution with @Timmain's post [cant-scale-multiple-paths-in-raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171635/cant-scale-multiple-paths-in-raphael)

using [ScaleRaphaël](http://www.shapevent.com/scaleraphael/) and by adding

```
    this.toFront();
    this.scale(1.2);
```

so my hover is now

```
'obj
.hover(function(){ 
    if(paths[arr[this.id]].value == 'notSelected')
        {
        this.animate({
            fill: '#32CD32'
        }, 300);
    }
    this.toFront();
    this.scale(1.2);'
```

I got the effect I was after.

Comment: I spoke too soon. This does not work in IE6,8 or 9

so I changed it to 
' this.toFront();
this.animate({
transform: 'S1.2'}, 100); '
and it still doesn't work on IE :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm on iPod but I think you may find this interesting and maybe help you 2

http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?q=dynamichorizontalmenu

It shows scaling as part of the transform

Hope it helps